# Assignment to DataFrame not working but dtypes changed

Tags: python, pandas

**Assignment to DataFrame not working but dtypes changed.**

New to data-science, I wanna assign the `target_frame` to the `empty_frame`, but it's not working until assign again. And during the assignments, the `dtypes` of `empty_frame` has changed from `int32` to `float64` and finally setup to `int64`.

I try to simplify my model as the code below, they have the same problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataset = [[[i for i in range(5)], ] for i in range(5)]
dataset = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns=['test'])  

empty_numpy = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
empty_numpy.fill(np.nan)

# Solution 1: change the below code into 'empty_frame = pd.DataFrame(empty_numpy)' then everything will be fine
empty_frame = pd.DataFrame(empty_numpy, columns=[str(i) for i in range(5)])

series = dataset['test']
target_frame = pd.DataFrame(list(series))

# Solution 2: run `empty_frame[:] = target_frame` twice, work fine to me.
# ==================================================================
# First try.
empty_frame[:] = target_frame
print("="*40)
print(f"Data types of empty_frame: {empty_frame.dtypes}")
print("="*40)

print("Result of first try: ")
print(empty_frame)
print("="*40)


# Second try.
empty_frame[:] = target_frame

print(f"Data types of empty_frame: {empty_frame.dtypes}")
print("="*40)

print("Result of second try: ")
print(empty_frame)
print("="*40)
# ====================================================================
```

I expect the output of code above should be:

```
========================================
Data types of empty_frame: 0    int64
1    int64
2    int64
3    int64
4    int64
dtype: object
========================================
Result of first try: 
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  1  2  3  4
1  0  1  2  3  4
2  0  1  2  3  4
3  0  1  2  3  4
4  0  1  2  3  4
========================================
```

but it's not working when I first try.

There are two solutions for this problem but I don't know why:

- as I showed in my code, try the assignment twice in one run.
- remove the columns' name when creating `empty_frame`.

Two things I want to figure out:

1. why `empty_frame`'s data types changed.
2. why the solutions showed in my code can solve this assignment problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly, then your problem starts when you create empty_numpy matrix.
My favourite solution would be to use *empty_numpy = np.empty([5,5])* instead (default dtypes is float64 here). Then the "Result of first try: " is correct. It means:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataset = [[[i for i in range(5)],] for i in range(5)]
dataset = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns=['test'])  

empty_numpy = np.empty([5,5])
# here you may add empty_numpy.fill(np.nan) but it's not necessary,result is the same

empty_frame = pd.DataFrame(empty_numpy, columns=[str(i) for i in range(5)])

series = dataset['test']
target_frame = pd.DataFrame(list(series))

# following assignment is correct then
empty_frame[:] = target_frame
print('='*40)
print(f'Data types of empty_frame: {empty_frame.dtypes}')
print('='*40)

print("Result of first try: ")
print(empty_frame)
print("="*40)
```

Or just add dtype attribute to your np.arrange call, just like this:

```
empty_numpy = np.arange(25, dtype=float).reshape(5, 5)
```

Then it works too (but it's a little boring ;o).

Comment: Thanks for your solution. from my understanding, it's because the type of `np.nan` is `float64` that failed the assignment. But there still something confuse me, why the same code outputs different. As you can see, I run this line `empty_frame[:] = target_frame` twice in my example, but got different result, it's unreasonable for me to make sense.

Comment: @KayCrazy your _target_frame_'s dtype is _int64_, but dtype of _empty_frame_ in your solution is _int32_ . The first assignment _empty_frame[:] = target_frame_ just makes conversion of _empty_frame_ to _float64_ - otherwise you could loose precision (when _target_frame_ would contain values > _int32_ range). The second run already assigns values (because _float64_ > _int64_ ). You can avoid this problem when you explicitly set _dtype_ in _np.arrange_ function or use _np.empty_ (float is default there). Is it sufficient explanation?